# SQL: Sum / Group By Issue for Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have looked elsewhere, but not managed to get an answer to this, so hoping someone with much more SQL experience can help me out on this!

I have the following portfolio table:

```
Ticker    Company_ID   Exposure
ABC         1            0.02
DEF         2            0.10
XYZ         3            0.01
GTS         3            0.01
```

And the following information table (where there are duplicates, with other information, and they cannot be deleted):

```
Company_ID   Company_Name
   1           Alpha
   2           Defacto
   2           Defacto
   3           XeeWhy
   3           XeeWhy
```

And I would like the result to be of the form

```
Company_ID   Company_Name   Sum(Exposure)
    1         Alpha           0.02
    2         Defacto         0.10
    3         XeeWhy          0.02
```

I can run something to get a simple sum from the portfolio table, but this does not include the company name:

```
Select Distinct Company_ID, Sum(Exposure)
From Portfolio
Group By Company_ID
```

But whenever I join the tables to get the Company Name, I get the sum duplicated depending how many times they appear in the Information table.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: where is your join clause? I don't see that in the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to join a subquery, that gets the distinct company information and a subquery getting the grouped portfolio data.

```
SELECT x1.company_id,
       x1.company_name,
       x2.exposure
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    company_id,
                    company_name
                    FROM information) x1
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id,
                              sum(exposure) exposure
                              FROM portfolio
                              GROUP BY company_id) x2
                      ON x2.company_id = x1.company_id;
```

I wasn't sure, if you want all companies in the result or only those, that have portfolio data. If you want the latter, change the `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH!! Will need to double check, but think this looks perfect!!

Answer (score 1):

Your simplest way would be to make the JOIN to your companies table DISTINCT, something like this:

```
Select p.Company_ID, 
    c.Company_name,
    Sum(Exposure) as Exposure
From Portfolio p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Company_id, Company_Name
    FROM Companies) c
    ON c.Company_id = p.Company_ID
Group By p.Company_ID,
    c.Company_Name
```

Comment: This does work. However, it only shows a few of the rows.

Comment: Then if I leave it, and re-run it shows a few more of the rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple query:

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 Company_Name FROM CompanyTable
        WHERE Company_ID = P.Company_ID) Company_Name,
       Sum(Exposure)
FROM Portfolio P
GROUP BY Company_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a CTE to get the Aggregation out of the way first:

```
Create table #portfolio (Ticker varchar(10), Company_ID int,Exposure decimal(10,2))
Insert into #portfolio values
('ABC', 1, 0.02),
('DEF', 2, 0.10),
('XYZ', 3, 0.01),
('GTS', 3, 0.01)

Create table #Information (Company_ID int,Company_Name varchar(10))
Insert into #Information values
   (1,'Alpha'),
   (2,'Defacto'),
   (2,'Defacto'),
   (3,'XeeWhy'),
   (3,'XeeWhy')


;WITH CTE as(
SELECT Company_ID, SUM(Exposure) EXP from #portfolio GROUP BY Company_ID 
) 
SELECT t1.Company_ID,t2.Company_Name, t1.EXP 
from CTE t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Company_ID, Company_Name from #Information) t2 on
  t1.Company_ID = t2.Company_ID
```